# Get unknown file content on a form application

Tags: c#

There is a file type with extension ".pop". I can open it with notepad.
I want to get this file's content line by line on my C# form application. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Is it `text file`? If it is you surely could do that...

Comment: Yes it is a text file. Should I write my program like reading from .txt file.

Comment: As a series of bytes, yes any file contents can be read. Provided these bytes are not encrypted or encoded in any odd way, and you have permission to read it, then yes you can open it and interpret it. Check out File.IO classes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is a text file you could use the [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("myfile.pop");
```

And then you could loop through the lines array or access individual lines by index. Note however that this will load the entire file contents in memory which might not be very good if the file is quite big. In this case you could read it line by line using a `StreamReader`:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead("myfile.pop"))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // do something with the line here
    }
}
```

In this case only a single line is loaded in memory.

Comment: What does stream object in first using block is meant for?

Comment: It's a `FileStream` instance returned by the `File.OpenRead` method. It is then passed to the second `StreamReader`.

Comment: It is not passed in StreamReader, you have file instead of stream

Comment: I think you have a little typo error between "stream" and "file" there.

Comment: Good catch for the typo :-) Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

If `myfile.pop` is in fact a *text file*, I suggest using `File.ReadLines` (which unlike `File.AllReadLines` reads the file line by line without loading all the file content into memory):

```
foreach(String line in File.ReadLines("myfile.pop")) {
  //TODO: put relevant code here
}
```